# on PKG_CONFIG_PATH setting

Tags: ffmpeg

I've installed ffmpeg on Ubuntu 16.04. Each time when I wanted to use `pkg_config_path` in a new terminal, I always had to type the following:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Is there a way where I can permanently set this path?

Answer (score 2):

You can set it permanently by appending it to your ~/.bashrc file .. use the command below:

```
echo 'export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$HOME/ffmpeg_build/lib/pkgconfig"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

or you can try this auto installer : https://github.com/razzbee/ffmpeg_installer
Disclaimer: I am the developer

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Added further explanation to the answer